# Python global variable name to be treated locally inside function

Tags: python

```
>>> x = 1
>>> def f():
...   print x
...
>>> f()
1

>>> x = 1
>>> def f():
...   x = 3
...   print x
...
>>> f()
3
>>> x
1

>>> x = 1
>>> def f():
...   print x
...   x = 5
...
>>> f()
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
  File "<stdin>", line 2, in f
UnboundLocalError: local variable 'x' referenced before assignment

>>> x = 1
>>> def f():
...    global x
...    print x
...    x = 5
...    print x
...
>>> f()
1
5
>>> x
5
```

How to treat the variable "**x**" inside the function as local without altering the global one when I have print statement above the variable assignment?

I expect the result of "**x**" to be 5 inside the function and the global x should be unaltered and remains the same in value (i.e) 1

I guess, there is no keyword called **local** in python contrary to **global**

```
>>> x = 1
>>> def f():
...   print x
...   global x
...   x = 5
...
<stdin>:3: SyntaxWarning: name 'x' is used prior to global declaration
```

Comment: What would you expect the result to be? Printing nothing/`None`/undefined? Or printing the value of the global variable?

Comment: Well, the error does say your `x` is local in there. It's just that it isn't assigned yet.

Comment: Locality is determined at the scope level, not the statement level. You cannot use the same name both locally and globally in the same scope.

Answer (score 2):

> In Python, variables that are only referenced inside a function are implicitly global. If a variable is assigned a value anywhere within the function’s body, it’s assumed to be a local unless explicitly declared as global.

[Source.](https://docs.python.org/3/faq/programming.html#what-are-the-rules-for-local-and-global-variables-in-python)

It's true there's no `local` keyword in Python; instead, Python has this rule to decide which variables are local.

Any variable in your function is either local or global.  It can't be local in one part of the function and global in another.  If you have a local variable `x`, then the function can't access the global `x`.  If you want a local variable while accessing the global `x`, you can call the local variable some other name.

Answer (score 1):

The behaviour is already what you want. The presence of `x =` inside the function body makes `x` a local variable which entirely shadows the outer variable. You're merely trying to print it before you assign any value to it, which is causing an error. This would cause an error under any other circumstance too; you can't print what you didn't assign.